# Extract C# Code From .exe

Tags: c#-2.0

Im facing a Problem my HDD died and I lost many application which I made on Visual C# But I have an exe for most of them as backup but no codes is there a program that extract the code from an .exe

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use

**[.NET Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)** for this

> .NET Reflector enables you to easily
>   view, navigate, and search through,
>   the class hierarchies of .NET
>   assemblies, even if you don't have the
>   code for them. With it, you can
>   decompile and analyze .NET assemblies
>   in C#, Visual Basic, and IL.

***Edit***

**[Reflector.FileDisassembler](http://www.denisbauer.com/NETTools/FileDisassembler.aspx)**

The Reflector.FileDisassembler is a little add-in for the new version of Lutz Roeder's .NET Reflector that you can use to dump the decompiler output to files of any Reflector supported language (C#, VB.NET, Delphi). This is extremely useful if you are searching for a specific line of code as you can use VS.NET's "Find in Files" or want to convert a class from one language to another.

Comment: Link to Reflector (I thought it would be rude to modify your answer:) - http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/

Comment: If you find any edit to be helpful to an answer then you can add that.

Comment: There is a specific reflector plugin that writes the reversed code out to disk- it is worth looking for that.

Answer (score 3):

Use [.net Reflector.](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/)
Naturally, extracting comments is impossible but you can get your sources back. You also won't be able to get the Visual Studio designer to work with it. But it's better than losing everything? I had to do this for one of my class libraries the other day.

Answer (score 1):

I've had luck with IL Spy as well, though I don't know if it has a module to dump source files.

> ILSpy is the open-source .NET assembly browser and decompiler.
>
> Development started after Red Gate announced that the free version of
>   .NET Reflector would cease to exist by end of February 2011.

http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ilspy.ashx